# Changing size of QR/bar code in Apple Wallet Passes

Tags: ios, passbook

When creating a pass for Apple Wallet, is there a way to change the size of the QR or barcode at the bottom? Apple supplies an example of the layout [Apple Wallet Pass layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAHEv.png), so is the size of the QR code shown at the bottom fixed or can it be changed in the pass.json file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can't change any sizes (fonts, QR codes) yet on a pkpass. You are only allowed to change its type (ean vs aztec vs etc.)

Comment: Thank you! That's helpful in itself.

Comment: Happen to know the official pixel size of Apple's QR codes? I'm trying to understand the max amount of data I can store ... Apple's documentation leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: @Dan as my using, there is no max amount. I used to make 3MB for a pass with big image size and full text paragraph.